# Microsoft Access: Select one email address per company

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that looks similar to this:

```
+---------+---------+-----------------+
| company |  type   |      email      |
+---------+---------+-----------------+
| ID001   | user    | user@email.com  |
| ID001   | admin   | admin@email.com |
| ID002   | user    | ...             |
| ID002   | admin   | ...             |
| ID002   | janitor | ...             |
| ID003   | admin   | ...             |
+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

I would like to `SELECT` all email addresses where the `type` = `user`. If `user` doesn't exist, it should select `admin`. If that also doesn't exists, it should select `janitor`, etc.

At the end I need a result with only one email address per company. I was able to sort by `type` and then use `SELECT TOP 1` like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
  contacts.company,
  contacts.type,
  contacts.email
FROM contacts
WHERE contacts.Email <> "" AND contacts.company = "ID001"
ORDER BY 
IIf([contacts.type] = 'user',1,
IIf([contacts.type] = 'admin',2,
IIf([contacts.type] = 'janitor',3,
4)))) ASC)
```

**This only works for one specific company, see the `WHERE` clause**. How can I make it work for the whole table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a conditional aggregate query with nested `IIF()`:

```
SELECT c.company,
       MAX(IIF(c.type = 'user' AND c.Email IS NOT NULL, c.Type,
               IIF(c.type = 'admin' AND c.Email IS NOT NULL, c.Type,
                   IIF(c.type = 'janitor' AND c.Email IS NOT NULL, c.Type, NULL)
                  )
               )
          ) As final_type,
       MAX(IIF(c.type = 'user' AND c.Email IS NOT NULL, c.Email, 
               IIF(c.type = 'admin' AND c.Email IS NOT NULL, c.Email,
                   IIF(c.type = 'janitor' AND c.Email IS NOT NULL, c.Email, NULL)
                  )
               )
          ) As final_email
FROM contacts c
GROUP BY c.company
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your table `contacts` does not have a primary key field, then you could use something along the lines of the following:

```
SELECT
    t.company,
    t.type,
    t.email
FROM
    contacts t
WHERE
    t.company & t.type =
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 
            contacts.company & contacts.type
        FROM 
            contacts
        WHERE 
            contacts.Email IS NOT NULL AND contacts.company = t.company
        ORDER BY 
            IIf([contacts.type] = 'user',1,
            IIf([contacts.type] = 'admin',2,
            IIf([contacts.type] = 'janitor',3,
            4))) ASC
    )
```

This assumes that the concatenation of the company & type will be unique within the dataset.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the table does not have a primary key (It's from a legacy system).

Comment: I got the `At most one record can be returned by this subquery` error message. Then I changed from `=` to  `IN` in the first `WHERE`, now it works. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @tontheman That would indicate that the combination `contacts.company & contacts.type` is not unique within your dataset, i.e. that there are multiple records of the same `type` for the same `company`. Nevertheless, glad you were able to solve it.